# How combine two SASS files in one CSS file via laravel mix?

Tags: css, laravel, webpack, sass, laravel-mix

How to correct combine multiple scss files in one css file?

My current configuration webpack.mix.js

```
mix.sass(
[
    'resources/assets/sass/one.scss',
    'resources/assets/sass/two.scss',
], 'public/css/style.css');
```

But it does not work.

I try first first mix.combined scss files, then mix.sass ...

But after 'npm run watch' i got looped crazy CLI.

Comment: You can have one main scss file and import everything in that

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of combining them through mix, import the stylesheets you need together in SCSS: https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-5

If you want to keep them separate, make a new stylesheet that just imports the needed styles.

Comment: @webdevdani Is something like this also possible for JS files?

Comment: @OzanKurt This depends on your JS build. If you're using modern build processes, you can use the regular ES2015 imports: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import